# Arcpy - Script toolbox - CreateObject cannot open map document

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a script that automates the entry of a shapefile of points through a spreadsheet in excel. Later he enters it into an ArcMap Document (alias "previous"), deletes the previous one and copies the symbology of a layer. Then it will be saved in another .mxd (later), the latter is exported as PDF and the process is finished.

BUT, when executing the script I get the error "CreateObject cannot open map document" when entering the ArcMap Document ("previous"), referring to an arcpy.GetParameterasText of the script:

[image]

I don't know what might be malfunctioning, as it used to run in a good way.

I leave you the code that I am using:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

#Declare parameters

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
capa_entrada_puntos = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
capa_entrada_buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Fecha_anterior = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Fecha_actualizacion = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

ENG_layer_anterior_puntos = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
ENG_layer_anterior_buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
ENG_layer_salida_puntos = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
ENG_layer_salida_buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)

#Definition of independent variables
ENG_layer_salida_puntos_simbologia = r"Path"
layer_salida_buffer_simbologia = r"Path"

#Geoprocess_ENG
ENG_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))
ENG_df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(ENG_mxd)[0]
for b in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(ENG_mxd,ENG_layer_anterior_puntos, ENG_df):
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(ENG_df,b)
for p in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(ENG_mxd,ENG_layer_anterior_buffer, ENG_df):
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(ENG_df,p)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(capa_entrada_puntos, ENG_layer_salida_puntos)
ENG_layer_puntos = arcpy.mapping.Layer(ENG_layer_salida_puntos)
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(ENG_layer_salida_puntos,ENG_layer_salida_puntos_simbologia)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(ENG_df,ENG_layer_puntos,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(capa_entrada_buffer,ENG_layer_salida_buffer)
ENG_layer_buffer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(ENG_layer_salida_buffer)
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(ENG_layer_salida_buffer,layer_salida_buffer_simbologia)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(ENG_df,ENG_layer_buffer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(ENG_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Fecha_ENG"):
    elm.text = elm.text.replace(Fecha_anterior, Fecha_actualizacion)

ENG_mxd_salida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
ENG_mxd.saveACopy(ENG_mxd_salida)

ENG_mxd_PDF = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(11)
PDF_mxd_eng = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(ENG_mxd_salida)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(PDF_mxd_eng,ENG_mxd_PDF)

del ENG_mxd
del ENG_df
del b
del p
del ENG_layer_anterior_puntos
del ENG_layer_anterior_buffer
del ENG_layer_salida_puntos
del ENG_layer_salida_buffer
del ENG_layer_puntos
del ENG_layer_buffer
del ENG_mxd_salida
del ENG_mxd_PDF
del PDF_mxd_eng

del capa_entrada_puntos
del capa_entrada_buffer
del ENG_layer_salida_puntos_simbologia
del layer_salida_buffer_simbologia

arcpy.AddMessage("Processes finished")
```

In the parameter configuration in the script in ArcCatalog it is as follows:

[image]

I have done many tests, and apparently, the name of the mxd is kept in memory because the execution of the script does not reach the moment of deleting the variables, but I am not 100% sure.

- The variables are in Spanish because it is my native language

Comment: My guess is you have the direction set to Output - and it seems like it should be set as an  Input. This is probably having negative effects on what the value is inside the code, being passed to the `MapDocument`

Comment: No, it was my mistake when printing the screen. It was always in Input. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, then my next guess is to use `arcpy.GetParameter(5)` (instead of AsText). There could be something going on with the `MapDocument` not liking the text, although I'd figure it should work. Or it could be an order thing; perhaps the GetParameter call isn't resolving when used directly to the MapDocument. Try breaking it into it's own variable and passing that in.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that illustrates what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck as formatted text rather than pictures. The same with any error messages you receive.

Comment: I used GetParameter but it didn't work either.